# SQL "Select" stripping needed dash character from value

Tags: sql

I have a basic SELECT statement that looks like this:

```
    Select Distinct currency.denomination From currency
```

Some values in my Currency table contain ranges, such as `10-50` but instead in these particular instances the query returns `1050` instead of the stored value range of `10-50`.

This is just one example, but all of the values that store the dash are being returned as one big number instead of the range.

What can I do to ensure the Select statement returns the dash which *is* stored, and needed for my use case?

Comment: Please create a `sqlfiddle.com` with your example.  If you're storing dashes, they should be returned (I don't know of any engines that would just strip them).

Comment: What database are you using? And show us the definition of your `currency.denomination` column.

Comment: I'm using the SQL engine in FileMaker.

Comment: The column definition in FileMaker was set to a Number, I just changed this to a text field and now I am getting the "-" returned.